# Beyond the Tour of Heroes

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am new to Angular, background is server side Java, .Net...

So, I completed the Tour of Heroes and I have created simple hard coded multi-page application. Now I need to go the next step and call the server to retrieve data via a rest/JSON call. Based on the AngularJS example: 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

and a few other blogs such as:
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html

I have a pretty good understanding of how it is supposed to work. However, I see two errors now:
*In the browser*: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'AuthService'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'AuthService' is decorated with Injectable.

*and in NPM*:
 app/auth.service.ts(9,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Http'.

I have no clue how to chase the dependencies down. packages.json? typings.json, tsconfig.json... Or how they all work; and I cannot find any documentation; any suggestions?

auth.service:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS}    from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    items:Array<any>;

    constructor(http:Http) {

    }
}
```

main.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, AuthService]);
```

I have not consumed the Auth.Service in an component yet.

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not pulling in Http, just HTTP_PROVIDERS, in your auth.service try this

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http'
```

Comment: Morgan, that was it. Any pointers on how to chase down the dependencies? I have not found any explanations on how it is all pieced together.

Comment: It's pretty hard right now as even the docs on the website are not complete.  What has helped me out a ton is using a good IDE, I use pycharm by IntelliJ, it will almost always tell me when I am not importing something correctly.  Otherwise the best bet would be to go here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiType=Class those classes are a giant list of I think all of the dependencies, problem is not all of them are up to date or even written yet.  I will say that there are 3 people on Angular2 stackoverflow that are fantastic resources and respond quickly.  Thierry, Gunter, and Mark.